# How to handover item._key from a listPage to a first editPage and second editPage

Tags: google-app-maker

I have a created a page that contains a list of reviews. If the user clicks on a name, he will be directed to a page where he can edit the review details if needed.

[image]

In order to achieve this I have adapted the methods from the travel approval template.

The names in the list are link widgets that contain the onClick event which I simply adapted from the template to get a quick result. The client script is integrated in the onAttach event of the page.

```
//button method    
if (event.ctrlKey === false && event.metaKey === false) {
      event.preventDefault();
      app.showPage(app.pages.ReviewDetails);
      replaceUrlForEditRequest(widget.datasource.item._key);
    }

//client script
function startLoadingEditRequestPage() {
  google.script.url.getLocation(function(location) {
    var requestId = location.parameter.requestId;
    var requestDs = app.datasources.Reviews;

    if (requestDs.creating) {
      return;
    }

    if (!requestId) {
      app.showPage(app.pages.Dashboard);
      return;
    }

    if (requestDs.loaded && requestDs.query.filters._key._equals === requestId) {
      return;
    }

    requestDs.unload();
    requestDs.query.filters._key._equals = requestId;
    requestDs.load();
  });
}
```

The handover to the edit page works perfectly. The user will see the review details of the person he has clicked on (ex: Mary Poppins) and not the one who has the active index in the list. If the user clicks on a link "personal information" in the review details page he will be directed to another edit page where he can see other information of the person. For this I have simply amended the method from the template by adding another target page to the history.

```
function replaceUrlForEditRequest(requestId) {
  var params = {
    requestId: requestId
  };

  google.script.history.replace(null, params, app.pages.EditReview.name);
  google.script.history.replace(null, params, app.pages.EditReviewDetails.name);
}
```

But when I duplicate the button method in the link on the review details page, it is not working. I always see the first name in my list and not the one that I had clicked on. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been resolved. Although both pages were on the same model, they were not on the same datasource. After setting them to the same datasource, everything works fine.